# How to get IV for decryption in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, encryption, cryptography, aes

I need to encrypt / decrypt a username field and I was planning to use the code below:

```
public class Decrypter {
    Cipher dcipher;

    byte[] salt = new String("12345678").getBytes();
    int iterationCount = 1024;
    int keyStrength = 256;
    SecretKey key;
    byte[] iv;

    Decrypter(String passPhrase) throws Exception {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount, keyStrength);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        key = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    }

    public String encrypt(String data) throws Exception {
        dcipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        AlgorithmParameters params = dcipher.getParameters();
        iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        byte[] utf8EncryptedData = dcipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
        String base64EncryptedData = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(utf8EncryptedData);

        System.out.println("IV " + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(iv));
        System.out.println("Encrypted Data " + base64EncryptedData);
        return base64EncryptedData;
    }

    public String decrypt(String base64EncryptedData) throws Exception {
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] decryptedData = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(base64EncryptedData);
        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(decryptedData);
        return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Decrypter decrypter = new Decrypter("ABCDEFGHIJKL");
        String encrypted = decrypter.encrypt("StringToBeEncrypted");
        String decrypted = decrypter.decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println(decrypted);
    }
}
```

I've taken this code from another site. The above code works fine when run as standalone. But the issue that I'm facing is how to decrypt the value when username is already encrypted?

I'll be calling encrypt & decrypt functions from different classes, so if the string is already encrypted & stored in the DB, then when user logs into website, when I'll call decrypt method, how do I pass the IV as CBC mode decrypt requires an IV parameter, while I've not stored iv during the encryption???

Any help is much appreciated!!

NOTE: This has nothing to do with password protection. As mentioned, need to encrypt userid & not password! For password protection, I'm using hash only.

Comment: You don't 'get' it, you *define* it, at both ends.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To decrypt you have to have the IV and the secret key.

Though it is less secure, what I've seen is that people always keep the key (or password) safe somewhere and sometimes just code the IV into the program.

```
byte[] iv = new byte[] 
{ 
0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09,0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f 
};
```

Or with some other set of byte values.

[Note that your code is generating an IV for each call to `encrypt()`]

*Edit*

Commenter @SLaks points out that using a constant IV reduces the level of protection and removes the extra level of security added by using CBC (which uses the IV). It reduces to the level of ECB (which has no IV).

(Note: in the code above:

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

where CBC is selected.)

This is significant in that a particular string of bytes will encrypt to the same result every time when the key, IV and salt used are the same. IV is there to make this stop happening.

We want the encrypted results to be as random looking as possible. That keeps the bad guys from figuring out the original content.

Think of the IV as adding randomness to the plain-text message. For example, you might be encrypting passwords people give you. Those people tend to choose poor passwords and multiple people tend to choose the same one. Adding randomness would be a good thing in this case.

Think of a salt as adding randomness to the passphrase (which is just a fancy word for password to highlight using a long and varied one). In this case, again, people choose poor ones and adding randomness to them makes the encrypted results more random.

That's why you would choose a random bunch of bits to serve as the IV for each message encrypted. To keep it from looking like other encrypted messages. But they have to be stored with each message so it can be decrypted.

Any choosing a random bunch of bits to serve as the salt for each person will serve to make their messages encrypt and look different from anyone elses messages. You could use a different salt each time the person logs in or each time they change their password or even just once per person. However you do it, you have to save the salt values so you can decrypt the messages later.

If you need this level of security, be sure to generate a truly random IV for each message encrypted and store it somewhere to be used when decrypting.

Comment: Can I use the code that u provided without having the need to pass IV during decryption? I know that it would be less secure but just want to know my options.

Comment: **DO NOT DO THIS**. This defeats the purpose of IVs, and is essentially the same as ECB.  Do not write crypto code unless you fully understand the operations you're using.  Otherwise, you are very likely to end up creating security holes or weaknesses.  _Leave crypto stuff to the experts_. (among whom I do not number)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the same. I'm just looking for various different options.

Comment: @RameshSippy: Yes; I'm primarily talking to Lee Meador, who probably has apps with security holes.

Comment: @SLaks Every application has security holes. You can break into my house by going in the window but I still lock the door. Security is not an absolute. Perhaps a hardcoded IV is good enough for an application that is putting things into a database. Particularly when the alternative is to store the IV right beside the data.

Comment: @SLaks If OP is storing weopons data or the Presidents secret list, he doesn't want to use AES anyway.

Comment: This is not crtical data that I'm encrypting. Even if it is hacked, there will not be any loss. And hence I'm exploring options.

Comment: "If you need this level of security, be sure to generate a truly random IV for each block encrypted and store it somewhere to be used when decrypting." - random IVs aren't needed for each block; only for each session.

Comment: In fact, you can't specify different IVs per-block.

Comment: Lending my downvote for reasons explained by SLaks. It's really easy to handle the IV correctly, so arguments based on low value of protected data are not persuasive.

Comment: Sorry @erickson, I disagree (respectfully) with your assertion that adding code (and database considerations) for storing of multiple IV's and adding logic to decide when to use which one is always "really easy." You are right that it might not be hard if you can easily control the database. What if you are restricted from modifying the database? It's really an engineering trade off. Does the work it takes buy you anything of that much value to you? Every case is different. But knowing the tradeoffs is important so thank you.

Comment: @LeeMeador if you can store CBC mode encryption then you already have at least 15 bytes overhead if any block is 1 or 17 bytes in size. In that case you are better off using 8 bytes random IV and CTR mode encryption. You would use less data and be more secure. Personally I would be very annoyed if you could find identical blocks for partially identical user names. Sure, you can play around with security parameters, but you should at least know what you are getting into. Just specifying an insecure solution without a warning is certainly not the way to go.

Comment: @owlstead Your comment highlights the trade-offs. We can secure things to a greater or lesser degree. Even that continuum depends on the possible attacks. A Captain Midnight Decoder Ring is good enough to keep wandering eyes from memorizing something. Sometimes that's all you need. OP didn't say whether he/she was encrypting food preferences, passwords or credit card numbers. We say "this is secure" and "that is insecure." We are wrong because secure is a scale not an absolute. A proper IV randomizes the plaintext. A proper salt (for a DB) randomizes the password. Maybe its worth the effort.

Comment: @LeeMeador Your explanation of the tradeoffs helps, and I changed "blocks" to "message" since you don't need a new IV for each block (the cipher text of the preceding block is the "IV"). With those changes, I'm not as uncomfortable with this answer.

Comment: "All programs have security holes" is not an excuse for knowingly writing security holes.  Not only is that argument self-defeating *(if he didn't care about secrecy, he wouldn't be encrypting in the first place)*, but, depending on the country/application, doing that could get you into legal trouble, even without "storing weapons data."  -1.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Please do not confuse my suggestion that all the costs and benefits be weighed before making things more secure with suggesting someone write security holes. You may answer the question "How much security is enough?" differently from someone else. Or you may have it answered for you by legal requirements or lack thereof OR perhaps, by budgets and timelines. Security is not an absolute.

Comment: @SLaks Note that CBC with a fixed IV is not essentially ECB. I agree with you though that CBC with a fixed IV is bad practice, weakens security, and should not be done.

Answer (score 8):

The IV is something you need to **supply** when encrypting or decrypting data.

Like salt for a hash, the IV ensures that the identical plaintexts will never result in indentical ciphertexts.

You need to generate a (securely) random IV when you encrypt each plaintext and store it alongside the ciphertext.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should save IV as well in the DB & pass it for decryption?

Comment: @RameshSippy: Exactly.  See my expanded answer.

Comment: I'm already generating IV during the encryption, so I'm assuming that I just need to store it as well so that I can pass it during the decryption. Just to be curious, without having IV involved, would it be possible to do encryption/decryption? I know it would be less secure but just want to know for my reference.

Comment: @RameshSippy: Yes, that's called ECB mode, which should not be used.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation

Comment: ok. But just for reference, what change would be needed to use ECB mode? I won't be using it but its good to know for knowledge

Comment: Change `CBC` to `ECB` and get rid of the IV.

Comment: One reason to use the IV (and CBC) anyway, even though it does not make the data more secure is that different applications can use different IV values and the same database and they don't accidentally decode each others data even if a bug in the application tries to do so.

Comment: @LeeMeador: In such situations, each application should use a unique _key_.

Comment: @RameshSippy if you use ECB for anything resembling a string you mainly need to get your head checked :P